# OSF.DDA.Error 9020 on Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Since a few days we get an error response 9020 on the call Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync. This code used to work flawless. Is there a Microsoft problem?

```
getMessageBody() {
  // call the async function to get the body 
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,{},
      (result) => {

         this.entityAnalyzeData.EntityItem.Properties.ContactProperty.Body = String(result.value);

        // inform listeners 
        this.mlBodySubject.next('ok'); 
      }
    );
```

The result is

```
OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: null, status: "failed", error: OSF.DDA.Error}
value: null
status: "failed"
error: OSF.DDA.Error
name: "GenericResponseError"
message: "Er is een interne fout opgetreden."
code: 9020
```

Thanks in advance for your attention!

Wilco

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue internally, are all of your users hitting this error? What platforms (windows, mac, web, ect) are they experiencing this issue on, and for desktop clients what versions are experiencing this issue?

Comment: Is this issue occurring in the Window opened using Office.context.mailbox.displayMessageForm() API ?

Comment: This seems to be a bug. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2398